# Finding certain characters in the text in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a textbox which is fed by parameters and last view going to be like that,

Mr. Someone <##value1##> is <##value2##>, <##value3##> .......<##value12##>

and my question is how to splitting the text by values.

Comment: Hi, didn't understood your question. But mabe `Regex` wil help:

var split = Regex.Split(text, "<##value[0-9]+##>");

Comment: Hi @SeyedMortezaMousavi, I figured out with your help. Thank you!